# Nuxtjs with i18n-iso-countries

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js

I am trying to use i18n-iso-countries to get a list of countries

What I usually do

```
/plugins/i18nCountries.js
import countries from 'i18n-iso-countries'

console.log(countries.getNames('en'))

function getNames (locale) {
  return countries.getNames(locale)
}



export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject('getNames', (locale) => { return getNames(locale) })
}
```

The `console.log(countries.getNames('en'))` statement prints to the console a list of country names

However, when I am inside a vue page/component

```
//somecomponent.vue
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script>

export default {
  created () {
    console.log(this.$getNames('en'))
  },
}
</script>
```

it prints out `{}`

What can I do to make this library accessible on the client?

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the languages you want to use. If you put the following below the import line, it should work:

```
countries.registerLocale(require("i18n-iso-countries/langs/en.json"));
```